# How to get all HTTP request headers in PHP, reliably and server-agnostic, without accessing Superglobals?

Tags: php, server, http-headers

PHP provides `getallheaders()` which is an alias for `apache_request_headers()`. Throughout the PHP history this method was "upgraded" to also support FastCGI and FPM, but it's not always provided that a "bleeding-edge" PHP version is actually available in real-life environments or that you always encounter "standard" Apache or Nginx servers.

As an alternative server-agnostic way one can iterate over the superglobal `$_SERVER` and filter on all keys starting with `HTTP_`. But accessing superglobals directly is bad practice and discouraged. For example, accessing `$_SERVER` should be done by using `filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'key')` -- but to do this I already need to know all possible keys, which won't work if I want to get all headers. Headers are arbitrary, nobody stops anyone from sending own headers: For example, sending a header `Foo: Bar` ends in `$_SERVER['HTTP_FOO'] => 'Bar'`.

So, how can I reliably get all HTTP request headers on all possible server software that run a *modern* (but not neccessarily *latest*!) PHP version *without accessing superglobals directly*?

Comment: Maybe [symfony http foundation](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation) can help you?

Comment: @marv255 They are doing the approach of accesing `$_SERVER` directly. This is what I want to avoid (this approach is actually not only superglobal access, but also error-prone string matching/parsing).

Comment: But still there are a big community and brilliant testing. A lot of fast and secure applications use it. I think that it may be used just as an abstraction and there is no need to know what does it have behind.

Comment: Symfony is simply accessing $_SERVER and looks for HTTP_ keys. I just looked it up, it's open source after all. Also Symfony is just PHP code itself, written by arbitrary people. Sometimes it can provide some useful alternatives on how to do things, but it's by no means the only way. My question is not how Symfony does it (I know how Symfony does it and it's taking the path I'd like to avoid, if possible).